# How can i use the list in one function which has some data added in another function

Tags: c#, wpf, list, function, wcf

So here is my first file QuizzyService:

```
    List<Question> newQuestions = new List<Question>();
    public static List<Question> QuizzyServiceQuestions()
    {
        using (Stream stream = File.Open("..\\Debug\\questions.bin", FileMode.Open))
        {
            var binaryFormatter = new BinaryFormatter();
            return (List<Question>)binaryFormatter.Deserialize(stream);
        }
    }

    int curQuestion = 0;

    
    public Question NewGame(int questionCount) 
    {
        Random r = new Random();
        for(int i = 0; i < questionCount; i++)
        {
            Question x = QuizzyServiceQuestions()[r.Next(0, QuizzyServiceQuestions().Count)];
            while (newQuestions.Contains(x))
            {
                x = QuizzyServiceQuestions()[r.Next(0, QuizzyServiceQuestions().Count)];
            }
            newQuestions.Add(x);
        }
        Console.WriteLine(newQuestions.Count);
        return newQuestions[0];
    }

    public int CheckAnswer(int questionId, int answerId)
    {
        List<int> IdList = new List<int>();
        for (int i = 0; i < QuizzyServiceQuestions().Count; i++)
        {
            IdList.Add(QuizzyServiceQuestions()[i].Id);
        }
        return IdList.Single(i => i == questionId);
    }

    public Question GetNextQuestion()
    {
        curQuestion += 1;
        Console.WriteLine(newQuestions.Count);
        //Console.WriteLine(curQuestion);
        //Console.WriteLine(this.newQuestions.Count);
        return newQuestions[curQuestion];
    }
```

Here the relevant part of the xaml.cs file:

```
    private int totalQuestionCount;
    private int currentQuestionCount = 1;
    private int correctAnswerCount;
    Question newQuestion = new Question();

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void btnNewGame_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!int.TryParse(tbQuestionCount.Text.Trim(), out totalQuestionCount))
        {
            tblStatus.Text = "Invalid question count!";
            return;
        }

        correctAnswerCount = 0;
        tblStatus.Text = string.Empty;


        using(WpfQuizzyClient.QuizzyRef.QuizzyServiceClient client = new WpfQuizzyClient.QuizzyRef.QuizzyServiceClient("WSHttpBinding_IQuizzyService"))
        {
            newQuestion = client.NewGame(Convert.ToInt32(totalQuestionCount));
            UpdateUserInterface(newQuestion);
        }


    }

    private void btnAnswer_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Button button = (Button)sender;
        int answerId = -1;
        switch (button.Name)
        {
            case "btnAnswerA": answerId = 0; break;
            case "btnAnswerB": answerId = 1; break;
            case "btnAnswerC": answerId = 2; break;
            case "btnAnswerD": answerId = 3; break;
            default:
                // This should never happen
                MessageBox.Show("Invalid button name detected - contact support!");
                return;
        }



        using (WpfQuizzyClient.QuizzyRef.QuizzyServiceClient client = new WpfQuizzyClient.QuizzyRef.QuizzyServiceClient("WSHttpBinding_IQuizzyService"))
        {
            if (answerId == client.CheckAnswer(newQuestion.Id, answerId))
            {
                tblStatus.Text = string.Empty;
                tblStatus.Text = "Correct! Total: " + currentQuestionCount + " / " + totalQuestionCount;
                currentQuestionCount += 1;
                UpdateUserInterface(client.GetNextQuestion());
            }
            else
            {

                tblStatus.Text = string.Empty;
                UpdateUserInterface(client.GetNextQuestion());
            }
        }
```

My problem is that when i trigger btnAnswer_Click it doesnt have the list which has been created in NewGame but im not allowed to do something like NextQuestion(Question questionList)

If you need more info just tell me and i'll make sure to provide more as quickly as possible!

Comment: by the look of thing NewGame, CheckAnswer and GetNextQuestion shuld not be in service. move them to view controller

Answer (score -2):

i found the fix ... i just had to remove both using and add the "WpfQuizzyClient.QuizzyRef.QuizzyServiceClient client = new WpfQuizzyClient.QuizzyRef.QuizzyServiceClient("WSHttpBinding_IQuizzyService")" before the MainWindow()